# How to use Taylor series to get $e^x\geq1+x$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, taylor-expansion

I know that from $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^i}{i!}\right)$$ we can get the inequality $e^x\ge1+x$. But how?

Comment: What do you get if you expand the series?

Comment: Hint: this is relatively easy for $x\geq 0, x\leq -1$. For $-1<x<0$ group terms in pairs.

Comment: Look at the partial sums. Isn't $P_n(x)\geq 1+x$?